# Debugging 404 error with nginx+uwsgi+flask on Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm looking for help for what I assume is a configuration error with nginx...

My uwsgi .ini file is located at `/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/api/calc`:

```
[uwsgi]
#application's base folder
base = /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/api/calc

#python module to import
app = hello
module = %(app)

home = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/api/calc/%n.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket    = 666

#the variable that holds a flask application inside the module imported at line #6
callable = app

#location of log files
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

My nginx configuration is using letsencrypt/certbot to serve two domains. The mysite.com domain is also set up to serve an **api** subdomain. The relevant nginx **server** block is:

```
server {
      server_name api.mysite.com;

     root /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/api;

     index index.html index.htm;

     location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
     }

     location /calc/ {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/api/calc/calc_uwsgi.sock;
     }


    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I'm trying to create an API located at api.mysite.com/calc/ by adding a **location** block that specifies the uwsgi gateway defined in /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/api/calc.

With uwsgi running, when I access https://api.mysite.com/calc, the uwsgi log file shows that my python is being invoked and is generating response data:

```
[pid: 34683|app: 0|req: 24/24] 192.168.1.1 () {56 vars in 1127 bytes} [Sun Feb 21 18:26:01 2021] GET /calc/ => generated 232 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 87 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

The nginx access.log shows the access:

```
192.168.1.1 - - [21/Feb/2021:18:50:33 -0500] "GET /calc/ HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 13505.73.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.109 Safari/537.36"
```

But the client gets back a **404 not found** error. There is no entry in the nginx error.log file.

(Obviously) I don't know what I'm doing. I've tried a bunch of different things in the nginx configuration, but no love.

Any suggestions appreciated!

**Update**

I had assumed that with this configuration, a request to app.mysite.com/calc would be served by the "/" route in my python, but it appears that it is actually served by the "/calc/" route:

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World - '/' route "

@app.route("/calc/")
def hellocalc():
    return "Hello world - '/calc/' route "
```

Is there a way to configure this so that my python doesn't need to include 'calc' in all of its routes?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working using the internal routing route-uri directive

```
[uwsgi]
#try rewrite routing
route-uri = ^/calc/?(.*)$ rewrite:/
```

This necessitated reinstalling uwsgi after installing the pcre:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre
pip3 install -I --no-cache-dir  uwsgi
```

But here's another question: I did not install uwsgi with sudo, so now it lives in

```
/home/me/.local/bin/uwsgi
```

Is this good or bad?

Answer (score 0):

You can change permissions like sudo chmod 775 -R /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/api/calc/ also the same on working directory of your app /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/api/calc and aftewards in your .ini file chmod-socket = 660 after that do not run certbot whithout further research beacouse of that server starting to return 404 error.Also no matter to use uwsgi in ///.local/bin/uwsgi deliver it's location in your .ini file